# Sum of divisors and Euler phi function of a number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

[image]

I can very well see that all prime numbers satisfies this condition.

But what about other numbers, does there exist other solutions?

How do I find them?

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: so $\phi(n) = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) n/d$ and $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d | n} d$ so it asks $ 2n = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) n/d + \sum_{d | n} d = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) n/d + \sum_{d | n} n/d = \sum_{d | n} (\mu(d)+1) n/d $ i.e $\sum_{d | n} (\mu(d)+1)/d = 2$

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} \geqslant \prod_{p \mid n} \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{p}\biggr)$$

Comment: so for every $d |n$, $d \ne 1 \implies \mu(d) = -1$ i.e. $n = p$